# Alternatives of Flask APIs in tornado (Dialogflow webhook)

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es, tornado, webhooks

I need to create a webhook for Dialogflow in Tornado server. I had done this previously using flask. I'm a beginner in both of them. The code for flask
Flask webhook code :

```
from flask import render_template
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response
import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))
    res = makeWebhookResult(req)
    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)
    print("+++++++++++++++RESPONSE+++++++++++++++++", res)
    r = make_response(res)
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r

# Right now I'm just printing a response to see if it works properly

def makeWebhookResult(req):
      queryResult = req.get('queryResult').get("queryText")
      speech =  queryResult       
      return {
            "fulfillmentText": 'YOLO',
            "source": 'App'
        }

#./ngrok http 8090
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8090))
    print("Starting app on port %d" % (port))
    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='localhost')
```

Now I tried this in tornado like this :

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web as web
import tornado
import json
import os

static_root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = "./templates/index.html"
        self.render(template)


class Webhook(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type", "").startswith("application/json"):
            self.req = json.loads(self.request.body)
            print(self.req)
            print(json.dumps(self.req, indent=4))
            response = self.webhook_result(self.req)
            response = json.dumps(response, indent=4)
            response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            return response

    def webhook_result(self, *args):
            queryResult = self.req.get('queryResult').get("queryText")
            speech = queryResult
            print(speech)
            return {
                "fulfillmentText": 'YOLO',
                "source": 'App'
            }

handlers = [
    (r'/', MainHandler),
    (r'(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': static_root}),
    (r'/webhook', Webhook,)

]
settings = dict(
    debug=True,
    static_path=static_root
)

application = web.Application(handlers, **settings)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 8090
    application.listen(port)
    print(f"Server running on port : {port}")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

It works fine with Flask. 
When I try to run this through tornado (using ngrok for tunneling) I get a **WARNING:tornado.access:405 POST /webhook (127.0.0.1) 0.83ms**

I read tornado's docs but I still can't seem to figure out how do I go about this. I'm assuming the problem lies in the Webhook class. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe you should create method `def post()` in class `Webhook` - similar to `def get()` in `MainHandler`

Comment: after testing some code I'm sure you have to use name `def post()` instead of `def prepate()` to handle `POST` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning shows problem with `POST` request - and to handle `POST` you need method `def post()` in class `Webhook`.

It should be `post()` instead of `prepare()` (which is for something different).
And you can use `self.write(dictionary)` to send it as `'application/json'`

```
class Webhook(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type", "").startswith("application/json"):
            data_input = json.loads(self.request.body)

            print('data_input:', data_input)
            print('data_input json.dumps:', json.dumps(data_input, indent=4))

            data_output = self.webhook_result(data_input) # get as normal dict, not string

            print('data_output:', data_output)
            print('data_output json.dumps:', json.dumps(data_output, indent=4))

            self.write(data_output) # it will send as JSON
        else:
            self.write({'error': 'Wrong Content-Type'}) # it will send as JSON
```

BTW: if you send value to `webhook_result()` then you could get this value - ie as `data` - and use it instead of `self.req`

```
    def webhook_result(self, data):
        speech = data.get('queryResult').get("queryText")

        print('speech:', speech)

        return {
            "fulfillmentText": 'YOLO',
            "source": 'App'
        }
```

---

Code which I tested

```
import tornado
import tornado.web
import json
import os


static_root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname('.'), 'static')


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        #self.render("./templates/index.html")

        # to test POST request but with wrong Content-Type
        self.write('''<form action="/webhook" method="POST"><button>SUBMIT</button></form>''')


class Webhook(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type", "").startswith("application/json"):
            data_input = json.loads(self.request.body)

            print('data_input:', data_input)
            print('data_input json.dumps:', json.dumps(data_input, indent=4))

            data_output = self.webhook_result(data_input) # get as normal dict, not string

            print('data_output:', data_output)
            print('data_output json.dumps:', json.dumps(data_output, indent=4))

            self.write(data_output) # it will send as JSON
        else:
            self.write({'error': 'Wrong Content-Type'}) # it will send as JSON

    def webhook_result(self, data):
        speech = data.get('queryResult').get("queryText")

        print('speech:', speech)

        return {
            "fulfillmentText": 'YOLO',
            "source": 'App'
        }


handlers = [
    (r'/', MainHandler),
    (r'/webhook', Webhook),
    # probably it should be as last
    #(r'(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': static_root}),
]

settings = dict(
    debug=True,
    static_path=static_root
)

application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 8090
    application.listen(port)
    print(f"Running: http://127.0.0.1:{port}")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

---

Code which I used to send `POST` request with JSON data:

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/webhook'

data = {'queryResult': {'queryText': 'Hello World'}}

r = requests.post(url, json=data)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers.get('Content-Type'))
print(r.json())
```

---

**BTW:** In Flask you could do

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    data_input = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    data_output = makeWebhookResult(data_input)
    return jsonify(data_output)
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. In terms of minimizing and improving code too. :D.